# Code API default signature gsuite email in admin

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am not sure how to input the code and location input the code for gsuite. So it is set up as default for each employee

Comment: kindly add more information about your question

Comment: The tag seems wrong, this is not related to the G Suite Marketplace.